# Behind on CUs - Apply all or just latest?

Tags: 2010

We are about 4 CUs behind on our 2010 farm (3 WFEs, 3 Apps).  We have received conflicting information as to the need to apply all CUs since the last one we applied or just the most recent.  Some info shows all CUs are not really cumulative.

What is best method to get fully up-to-date?  Apply all CUs or just most recent?

Answer (score 1):

Apply the latest Service Pack and then apply the most recent CU that you need.  Microsoft only recommends applying CUs if you are experiencing one of the issues fixed in the CU.  CUs contain all hotfixes released since the latest Service Pack so there is never a need to apply more than one at any given time.

Comment: SP is current.  We have a few issues that many of the CUs would fix.  With SP2 potentially on the horizon, we may just wait.